# Oracle SQL percentages in a single query

Tags: oracle

So far I've got:

```
SELECT bike_no, maint_fault_details, maint_action_taken, 
       maint_fault_date, maint_action_date
FROM mainthistory
WHERE (maint_fault_date + 5) < maint_action_date ;
```

Trying to get it so that it displays the results as a percentage, ie, 10% of bikes took longer than 5 days to repair. Any idea's/suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will count all entries for which the condition is true and divide it by the number of rows.

```
SELECT 100 * SUM( CASE WHEN (maint_fault_date + 5) < maint_action_date
                   THEN 1
                   ELSE 0 END
       ) / COUNT(*) AS percentage
FROM mainthistory;
```

Comment: Thanks, how would I rename the percentage column that comes up?

Comment: By changing the alias after `AS` to something else.